# make CAShapeLayer and CGPath conform to Codable or to NSCoding

Tags: swift, codable, cashapelayer, nscoding, decodable

I'm trying to save and get info about CAShapeLayers at .json files, using Codable protocol, but have an error:

```
public class Node: Codable {


public var name: String = ""

public var path: CGPath?
    
public var baseLayer: CAShapeLayer?


public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: NodeCodingKeys.self)
           
    let _name = try container?.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: NodeCodingKeys.name)
    
    let _baseLayer = try container?.decodeIfPresent(CAShapeLayer.self, forKey: NodeCodingKeys.baseLayer)
    name = _name ?? ""
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: NodeCodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: NodeCodingKeys.name)
}
}

public enum NodeCodingKeys: CodingKey {
    
    case path
    case name
    case baseLayer
    
}
```

[image]

And the same for CGPath. Is there any way to save/receive them to/from device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to make `CAShapeLayer` conforms to `Codable`, so I created class for my data object:

```
public class ImageNode: NSObject, NSCoding, NSSecureCoding {
    public static var supportsSecureCoding = true
    var name: NSString
    var baseLayer: CAShapeLayer
    
    init(name: NSString,
         baseLayer: CAShapeLayer
         ) {
            self.name = name
            self.baseLayer = baseLayer
        }
    
    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(baseLayer, forKey: "baseLayer")        
    }
    
    public required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        guard let name = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? NSString
            else { return nil }
        guard let baseLayer = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "baseLayer") as? CAShapeLayer
            else { return nil }
             
        print("decode node")
            self.init(
                name: name,
                baseLayer: baseLayer
            )
    } }
```

which works nice with `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` for saving data to file and retrieving it. Maybe this solution will helps someone.